# Replace character on Shell string

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I'm currently making a connect 4 game on Unix.

I did 6 arrays of string which contain `Array[0]="_ _ _ _ _ _ _"` for the board.

The problem now is that I need to replace each blank space `_` by a `X` when a player place his pawn.

If the user select the position 3, `array[0]` should be like: `_ _ X _ _ _ _`.

Can someone explain me how to make that ?

Comment: unix is not a programming language

Comment: Sorry, by Unix i meant Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array[0]="_ _ _ _ _ _ _"
array[0]=${array[0]:0:4}X${array[0]:5}
echo ${array[0]}
```

output:

```
_ _ X _ _ _ _
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
$ r="_ _ _ _ _ _ _"
$ pos=3
$ echo "$r" | sed "s/_/X/$pos"
_ _ X _ _ _ _
$ pos=4
$ echo "$r" | sed "s/_/X/$pos"
_ _ _ X _ _ _
```

By saying `sed "s/_/X/N"` you are replacing the `N`th occurrence of `_` with a `X`.

Comment: A more generic approach with `Array` can be done, but for this I would need more context.